# Toggle table rows as per drop down

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a static html5 table with 4 rows. i want to show only first row on opening and then user decide to see how many rows from a dropdown.

HTML code:

```
<label for="noOfChild"> No of children: </label>
<select class="childSelect">
   <option value="1" selected>one</option>
   <option value="2">two</option>
   <option value="3">three</option>
   <option value="4">three +</option>
</select>
<table id="table">
   <tr>
      <th>No. of Child accounts</th>
      <th>Online Price</th>
      <th>Program Price</th>
      <th class="align-right red">Subscription Saving (25%)</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td class="align-right">£99.99</td>
      <td class="align-right">£74.99</td>
      <td class="align-right red">£25.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td class="align-right">£169.98</td>
      <td class="align-right">£127.48</td>
      <td class="align-right red">£42.50</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td class="align-right">£239.97</td>
      <td class="align-right">£179.97</td>
      <td class="align-right red">£60.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Three +</td>
      <td class="align-right">£239.97</td>
      <td class="align-right">£179.97</td>
      <td class="align-right red">£60.00</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

as i am no proficient in jquery i have written a basic function but dont know what to do now

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("select.childSelect").change(function(){
        var noOfChild = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        //hide rows

    });
});
```

[Code Snippet](https://codepen.io/MARahman49/pen/WmKJwO?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select.childSelect").change(function () {
            $('#table tr').hide();
            $('#table tr').eq(0).show();

            var noOfChild = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            for(var i = 1; i <= noOfChild; i++){
                $('#table tr').eq(i).show();
            }
        });
    });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xzfo80c7/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [lt-selector](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

> Description: Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.

2. Add the data in tbody and add the header in the thead of the table to avoid confusion

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.childSelect").change(function() {
    $("#table tbody tr").hide();
    var noOfChild = $("option:selected", this).val();
    //hide rows
    $("#table tbody tr:lt(" + (noOfChild) + ")").show();
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="noOfChild"> No of children: </label>
<select class="childSelect">
  <option value="1" selected>one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="4">three +</option>
</select>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No. of Child accounts</th>
      <th>Online Price</th>
      <th>Program Price</th>
      <th class="align-right red">Subscription Saving (25%)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td class="align-right">£99.99</td>
      <td class="align-right">£74.99</td>
      <td class="align-right red">£25.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td class="align-right">£169.98</td>
      <td class="align-right">£127.48</td>
      <td class="align-right red">£42.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td class="align-right">£239.97</td>
      <td class="align-right">£179.97</td>
      <td class="align-right red">£60.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Three +</td>
      <td class="align-right">£239.97</td>
      <td class="align-right">£179.97</td>
      <td class="align-right red">£60.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.childSelect").change(function() {
    var noOfChild = (+$(this).val() + 1 );
    $("#table tr").hide();
    $("#table tr:lt("+noOfChild+")").show();
  });
});
```

When you changes the `select` then it will `hide` all the `tr` and then `show` `x` amount corresponding to your `select` value

**demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.childSelect").change(function() {
    var noOfChild = (+$(this).val() + 1 );
    $("#table tr").hide();
    $("#table tr:lt("+noOfChild+")").show();
  });
});
```

```css
table tr {
  display: none;
}

table tr:first-of-type,table tr:first-of-type + tr {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="noOfChild"> No of children: </label>
<select class="childSelect">
  <option value="1" selected>one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="4">three +</option>
</select>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>No. of Child accounts</th>
    <th>Online Price</th>
    <th>Program Price</th>
    <th class="align-right red">Subscription Saving (25%)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td class="align-right">£99.99</td>
    <td class="align-right">£74.99</td>
    <td class="align-right red">£25.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td class="align-right">£169.98</td>
    <td class="align-right">£127.48</td>
    <td class="align-right red">£42.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td class="align-right">£239.97</td>
    <td class="align-right">£179.97</td>
    <td class="align-right red">£60.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Three +</td>
    <td class="align-right">£239.97</td>
    <td class="align-right">£179.97</td>
    <td class="align-right red">£60.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in other answers you have to iterate all rows to show / hide. If you have a lot of rows you can iterate once by checking the value.

Also, you don't need to use a selector to retrieve the `select` value as it is populated by dom in `select` itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.childSelect").change(function() {
    var $trs = $('#table tr');
    var noOfChild = this.value;
    for (var i = 0, len = $trs.length; i < len; i++) {
      var $tr = $trs.eq(i);
      if (i <= noOfChild) {
        $tr.show();
      } else {
        $tr.hide();
      }
    }
  });
  $("select.childSelect").change();
});
```

```css
.align-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

table {
  border: 1px black solid;
}

table tr th {
  border-bottom: 1px #a1a1a1 solid;
}

table tr td,
table tr th {
  border-right: 1px #a1a1a1 solid;
}

table tr td:last-child,
table tr th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

table tr:first-child {
  display: table-row;
}

table#table tr:not(first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="noOfChild"> No of children: </label>
<select class="childSelect">
  <option value="1" selected>one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="4">three +</option>
</select>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>No. of Child accounts</th>
    <th>Online Price</th>
    <th>Program Price</th>
    <th class="align-right red">Subscription Saving (25%)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td class="align-right">£99.99</td>
    <td class="align-right">£74.99</td>
    <td class="align-right red">£25.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td class="align-right">£169.98</td>
    <td class="align-right">£127.48</td>
    <td class="align-right red">£42.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td class="align-right">£239.97</td>
    <td class="align-right">£179.97</td>
    <td class="align-right red">£60.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Three +</td>
    <td class="align-right">£239.97</td>
    <td class="align-right">£179.97</td>
    <td class="align-right red">£60.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or, if you want to use selector you can re-elaborate [Carsten Løvbo Andersen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55236750/2277954) answer by changing the hide selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.childSelect").change(function() {
    var noOfChild = +this.value + 1;
    $("#table tr:gt(" + noOfChild + ")").hide();
    $("#table tr:lt(" + noOfChild +")").show();
  });
  $("select.childSelect").change();
});
```